# $\phi:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ with a given condition is measurable.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification, measurable-functions

$\phi:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is continuous at all points in  $\mathbb{R}^n-Y$ with $Y\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ of measure zero. Then $\phi$ is measurable. In the problem, the measure is the Lebesgue measure.

Proof) Let $c\in\mathbb{R}$. We prove $E:=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n:\phi(x)>c\}=(E-Y)\cup(E\cap Y)$ is measurable. First, $(E\cap Y)\subset Y$, so $m^*(E\cap Y)\leq m^*(Y)=0$ and $E\cap Y$ is measurable as it is measure zero.

Next, for all $x\in E-Y$, $\phi$ is continuous at $x$, so $\exists\delta>0$ such that $B_{\delta}(x)\subset E$. Then $E-Y=(\bigcup\limits_{x\in E-Y}B_{\delta}(x))-Y=(\bigcup\limits_{x_n\in E-Y}B_{\delta}(x_n))-Y$. For the last equality, we used the Lindeloff covering theorem to take countable balls. Then $E-Y$ is measurable as open sets are measurable, the union of countably many open sets is measurable, $Y$ is measurbale and the difference bewteen measurable sets is measurable.

I was wondering if this solutions is correct.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I just edited my question as a solution-verification question.

Comment: I read half the proof, it looks like you are using the same $\delta$ for all $x$, but we do not have any uniform continuity assumption. You also seem to assume every subset of a measure-zero set has measure 0. The first is easily fixed; the second depends on your assumptions about “completeness” of the measure.

Comment: Presumably you mean Lebesgue measurable?

Comment: Yes, I meant the Lebesgue measure. I just added a line for that in my post.